# How can I print this type of JSON in Android?

Tags: php, android, json

How can I print this type of JSON object in Android? It include jsonArray inside jsonObject.

This is my PHP file output:

```
           {
             "response": [
               { 
               "cat_id": "1",
               "cat_name": "abc",
                "cat_status": "1"
              },
              {
               "cat_id": "2",
               "cat_name": "abc",
               "cat_status": "1"
              },
              {
              "cat_id": "3",
              "cat_name": "abc",
              "cat_status": "1"



             }

             ]
             }
```

Comment: Do you want to print in logcat? If so, try `Log.d()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

**fisrt get your JSONArray like below**

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(JsonResponseString);// get JSONObject from respones 
JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("response");   // get JSONArray from json object
```

**now get your data from  jsonArray like below code**

```
for(int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++){

  JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);           // get your json object from array

  Log.d("cat_id", json_data.getString("cat_id"));          // get your cat_id

  Log.d("cat_name", json_data.getString("cat_name"));     // get your cat_name

  Log.d("cat_status", json_data.getString("cat_status"));// get your cat_status

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Log.d("Data", obj.toString());
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

you need to get it in an **String** type variable let say **responseString**
than follow the code

```
    JSONObject  jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(responseString);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("response");
    String result = "", cat_id = "", cat_name = "", cat_status = ""; 
    for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){  

                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);  
                            cat_id = jsonObject.optString("cat_id").toString();
                            cat_name = jsonObject.optString("cat_name").toString();
                            cat_status = jsonObject.optString("cat_status").toString();

    result += cat_id+"\n"+cat_name+"\n"+cat_status+"\n";                           
    }
textView_to_display_data_on_screen.setText(result);
```

it will print all your data in to textView (i.e here **textView_to_display_data_on_screen**).